# svn copy causes "...(403 Forbidden) in reponse to PROPFIND", other actions work

Tags: svn

Just for a short bit of background, the reason I'm tracking this particular subversion oddity down is because I found it troubleshooting our new Maven setup (specifically the release plugin). `release:prepare` gives me the same error buried in a stack trace.

Executing this command...
`svn copy http://[server]/svn/tran1/myproject/trunk http://[server]/svn/tran1/myproject/tags/testtag`

...gives me the following error:
`svn: Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to PROPFIND request for '/svn/tran1'`

I thought this might be an authentication issue, but I'm able to do pretty much every other subversion thing I can think of. Checkout, add, commit and update *all* work from the command line. And here's where it gets really weird... I can create branches using Eclipse's Subclipse plugin. This might not be all *that* strange if Eclipse isn't actually doing an `svn copy`.

tran1 also has a sibling subversion repository next to it. The copy command works fine there.

The URL it's trying to get permission for also looks wrong. It's asking about /svn/tran1, when the permissions are set up one level deeper /svn/tran1/myproject/

Any ideas what might be causing my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I vaguely remember encountering the same problem. I believe the problem turned out to be that you need at least read access to all parent folders up to the root of the repository in order to use the `svn copy` operation.

Comment: We have a winner! My group was granted read access to the parent and the svn copy command worked. Thank you SO much!

Comment: Sadly, the maven release:prepare is still failing for me. Same basic exception except instead of PROPFIND it says "..in reponse to OPTION". I'm seeing a lot more google/stack overflow hits on that error though, so I'll keep plugging along. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

After hours of trying to solve this, my boss finally worked it out.

I'll be as specific as possible, for the sake of newbies (like myself).

The short story:

> The httpd.conf was missing **COPY** in the  section.

Solution:

```
vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Look for:

```
<Limit GET PUT PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT MKACTIVITY CHECKOUT DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL MERGE COPY>
    Require valid-user
</Limit>
```

If **COPY** is not on the list, then add it.

Save your edited file.

Restart Apache:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

When I've seen this before, it comes down to Apache httpd configuration.  A 403 should correspond to an error in the logs for the server.  That should point you in the direction of the root cause.